Prove $a_n < \frac{1}{n-1}$
Let $n \ge 2$. Suppose that positive number series $a_0, a_1,..., a_{n+1}$ satisfies $$(a_{k-1}+a_k)(a_k+a_{k+1}) = a_{k-1}-a_{k+1}$$
Prove $a_n < \frac{1}{n-1}$
I have no idea how to solve this problem, but we can rewrite the assumption to
$$(a_{k-1} - a_k) -(a_k+a_{k+1})$$
$$\iff 1=\frac{1}{a_{k+1}+a_{k}}-\frac{1}{a_{k-1}+a_k}$$

@DS  Well, prior to the edit, it read a{k+1} so I assume the OP simple left off the underscore.  If I'm wrong, they should correct it.

Assuming you meant $a_{k+1}$ in your question, the equation can be written as
$$(a_k + a_{k-1})(a_k + a_{k+1}) = (a_{k-1} + a _k) - (a_k + a_{k+1}).$$
So, let
$$b_k = a_k + a_{k+1}$$
so that
$$ b_{k-1}b_k = b_{k-1} - b_k$$
and hence
$$\frac{1}{b_k} = \frac{1}{b_{k-1}}+1.$$
Again, let $c_k = \frac{1}{b_k}$
so that
$$c_k = c_{k-1} + 1 = c_{k-2} + 2 =  ... = c_0 + k > k$$
implying $ b_k < \frac{1}{k}$.
So,
$$b_{n - 1}= a_n + a_{n-1} > a_n$$
and hence
$$a_n < b_{n-1} < \frac{1}{n-1}$$
hence completing the proof.
